# MYSQL function with if elseif else

Tags: mysql, function, if-statement

How can I put it in a function which works with the set values e.g. function xy(@q,@p)

```
SET @q='10';
SET @p='5';
SELECT @a_rows := COUNT(*) FROM 'main1' WHERE status='0' && price<= @p && quantity >     '0';

IF @a_rows = '0' THEN

INSERT INTO detail1 (quantity,price,status) VALUES (@q,@p,'0');
INSERT INTO detail2 (quantity,price,status) VALUES (@q,@p,'0');

ELSEIF @a_rows='1' THEN
INSERT INTO detail3 (quantity,price,status) VALUES (@q,@p,'0');

ELSE 
; 
ENDIF
```

Comment: have you tried CASE WHEN.. THEN...??

Comment: No, but I need something that executes multiple inserts etc. depending on a condition or multiple condition ... I'm just confused about the basic template to do that

Comment: Why are you quoting integer values?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i dont know but i removed that from my test setup and answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do what I said in my previous comment... just use a case. like so.

**NOTE:** you cannot just run a bunch of inserts you have to case each insert respectively...

```
SET @q='10';
SET @p='5';
SELECT @a_rows := COUNT(*) FROM 'main1' WHERE status='0' && price<= @p && quantity >     '0';

INSERT INTO detail1 (quantity,price,status)
values
(
    (CASE @a_rows WHEN 0 THEN @q ELSE NULL END),
    (CASE @a_rows WHEN 0 THEN @p ELSE NULL END),
    (CASE @a_rows WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE NULL END)
);

INSERT INTO detail2 (quantity,price,status)
values
(
    (CASE @a_rows WHEN 0 THEN @q ELSE NULL END),
    (CASE @a_rows WHEN 0 THEN @p ELSE NULL END),
    (CASE @a_rows WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE NULL END)
);

INSERT INTO detail3 (quantity,price,status)
values
(
    (CASE @a_rows WHEN 1 THEN @q ELSE NULL END),
    (CASE @a_rows WHEN 1 THEN @p ELSE NULL END),
    (CASE @a_rows WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE NULL END)
);
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0897/1)

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I add ON DUPLICATE KEY UPdATE on the first insert? it returns a syntax error when I try it

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
CASE @a_rows 
WHEN 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO detail1 (quantity,price,status) VALUES (@q,@p,'0');
    INSERT INTO detail2 (quantity,price,status) VALUES (@q,@p,'0');
WHEN 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO detail3 (quantity,price,status) VALUES (@q,@p,'0');
ELSE 
    #If neither 0 or 1 
END CASE;
```